# Entity Framework 5.0 weird issue

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

I have the following database:

[image]

I have created the EDMX model out of this database.

Everything was working great, until the moment I added the `Diagnosis` table to the diagram.

The query below started to make errors:

```
var appointments = from a in db.Appointment.Include("Patient")
                   where a.DoctorID == doctorId
                   select a;
```

I started getting the following error:

> Invalid column name 'DiagnosisID'.

While in debugging mode, I checked the generated DB query, and it was :

```
SELECT 
  [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
  [Extent1].[DoctorID] AS [DoctorID], 
  [Extent1].[PatientID] AS [PatientID], 
  [Extent1].[DiagnosisID] AS [DiagnosisID], 
  [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
  [Extent1].[Time] AS [Time], 
  [Extent1].[Duration] AS [Duration], 
  [Extent1].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
  [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
  [Extent2].[ContactDetailID] AS [ContactDetailID], 
  [Extent2].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
  [Extent2].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
  [Extent2].[Sex] AS [Sex], 
  [Extent2].[BirthDate] AS [BirthDate], 
  [Extent2].[CurrentDate] AS [CurrentDate], 
  [Extent2].[Notes] AS [Notes1]
FROM  [dbo].[Appointment] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Patient] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PatientID] = [Extent2].[ID]
WHERE (([Extent1].[DoctorID] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[DoctorID] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent1].[DoctorID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))

/*
Int32 p__linq__0 = 1
*/
```

Anything wrong in my design?

Below is the Appointment table design:

[image]

And here is the FK definition for the Appointment Table:

[image]

The exception occurs once I call the **ToList()** method of the enumarable object as below:

[image]

The EF generated classes are as follows:

```
public partial class Appointment
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DoctorID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PatientID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DiagnosisID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Time { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> Duration { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public virtual Diagnosis Diagnosis { get; set; }
        public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
        public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public partial class Diagnosis
    {
        public Diagnosis()
        {
            this.Appointment = new HashSet<Appointment>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Symptoms { get; set; }
        public string Treatment { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CurrentDate { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointment { get; set; }
    }
```

EDMX generated classes are as below:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at your SQL database if everything is okay with Appointment table?

Comment: is `DiagnosisID` field name exactly matching with your column name in appointment table in database?

Comment: Yes they do match exactly the field name "DiagnosisID" as in database.

Comment: Please double/triple check your connection strings in your application to make sure that you are connecting to the right database!

Comment: Have you checked your .edmx model so that table mappings of Appointment and Diagnosis entities be correct?

Comment: Connection string is correct and it hits the right database.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try to run the same generated query in SQL Server Managment studio? Or only your application throws it?

Comment: I get no errors when I run the query in SSMS. This is what drives me crazy!

Comment: Have you tried deleting all entities and then re-updating from database? Make sure you save after you delete all entities.

Comment: Yes i tried to delete all tables in model, saved the model and then updated the model from database. same problem :(

Comment: @ZooZ Did you set the foreign key mapping between Diagnosis and Appointment? Even you don't query from Diagnosis, you still have to configure the relationship.

Comment: The mapping between Diagnosis and Appointment is automatically set by EF as shown in the generated classes above. shall I do extra steps?

Comment: @ZooZ One thing I am totally confused is you are saying you use EF 5, but why you still have access to edmx? edmx is only available in .net 3.5 and .net 4.0 or EF 4. from EF 4.1, there is no edmx

Comment: @sza that's just wrong. EDMX has always been available for all versions of EF, for later versions code-first was pushed forward but you always have the option.

Comment: @AlexPaven I don't think so.

Comment: @sza I'm currently (right at this moment) working with EF5 in VS2012 using database-first and modifying the EDMX. Please tell me why you don't think so. Edit: please also take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx

Comment: @ZooZ: the only thing I can think of is making sure you're generating the model and running the application off the same database... there's really no reason why this should happen unless the column really isn't there in the db I think (considering the source of the exception is really the SqlClient data provider).

Comment: @AlexPaven you are right. EDMX is always there for database-first models, even on EF 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem. It was in the connection string!
I forgot to change the conenction string as it was pointing to the production server, and I hadn't synchronized the DB changed back to the production database.

Thanks you guys for your efforts.